# java.util.NoSuchElementException reading user input

Tags: java, arrays

I'm getting an error message (java.util.NoSuchElementException) in thread main when attempting to compile the following code with the input 3, then 4, 5, and 7. I've tried to tweak the code, but there's something I'm missing. I was thinking it may be due to my use of arrays since I am just learning how to use those, but I've tried to look closely at them and I didn't see anything I did wrong, but I definitely missed something. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArrayMethods2 {
    public static int[] findMinAndMax(int[] x) {
        int i;
        int min = x[0];
        int max = x[0];
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (x[i] < min) {
                min = x[i];
            }
            if (x[i] > max) {
                max = x[i];
            }
        }
        int [] minAndMax = new int[2];
        minAndMax[0] = min;
        minAndMax [1] = max;
        return minAndMax;
    }
    public static double averageWithDrop(int[] x) {
        int i;
        int min = x[0];
        int minIndex1 = 0;
        int minIndex2 = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (x[i] < min) {
                minIndex1 = i;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (x[i] < min) {
                if (i != minIndex1)
                minIndex2 = i;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (i == minIndex1) {
                sum = sum + 0;
            }
            else if (i == minIndex2) {
                sum = sum + 0;
            }
            else {
                sum = sum + x[i];
            }
        }
        double average = sum / (x.length - 2);
        return average;
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many numbers would you like to enter? (must be at least 3) ");
        int userValue = scnr.nextInt();
        System.out.println(userValue);
        while (userValue < 3) {
            System.out.println("Invalid value, must be at least 3. Please try again ");
            userValue = scnr.nextInt();
            System.out.println(userValue);
        }
        int x = 0;
        int indexVal;
        int [] userArray = new int [userValue];
        while (x <= userValue) {
            System.out.print("Enter value for index " + x + ": ");
            indexVal = scnr.nextInt();
            System.out.println(indexVal);
            userArray[x] = indexVal;
            x++;
        }
        int [] minAndMaxVal = new int [2];
        minAndMaxVal = findMinAndMax(userArray);
        System.out.println("Min value: " + minAndMaxVal[1] + ", Max value: " + minAndMaxVal[2]);
        double avg = averageWithDrop(userArray);
        System.out.println("Average excluding two lowest values: " + avg); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problems in the code :

1. Update this `(x <= userValue)` to `(x<userValue)` , else it will give array index out of bounds exception
2. Start the for loop in minMaxFunction from 1 , since you have already stored the value of arr[0] to min and max like below . This is just an optimization in the code.

   ```
        for (i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (x[i] < min) {
                min = x[i];
            }
            if (x[i] > max) {
                max = x[i];
            }
        }
   ```
3. This line in main method should have index 0 and index 1 . There is no index 2 since you have declared the array of length 2 , else it will give array index out of bounds exception

   ```
     minAndMaxVal = findMinAndMax(userArray);
     System.out.println("Min value: " + minAndMaxVal[0] + ", Max value: " + minAndMaxVal[1]);
   ```

Comment: If you run the code there is no such exception . I am pretty sure .

Comment: i got the error he talked about.. check here http://tpcg.io/xk5pCJNO

Comment: @maha i think the issue is with the editor in that online tool. You need to pass the console input beforehand in the STDIN tab, then it works. Otherwise, it is working perfectly fine in standard IDEs

Answer (score 3):

Running your code, I did not get any `NoSuchElementException`, however I got `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Check the class your are running.

Please remember arrays are 0 based.

In the main method change `while (x <= userValue)`to `while (x < userValue)`

Again, arrays are 0 based, change:

```
System.out.println("Min value: " + minAndMaxVal[1] + ", Max value: " + minAndMaxVal[2]);
```

to

```
System.out.println("Min value: " + minAndMaxVal[0] + ", Max value: " + minAndMaxVal[1]);
```